# Vuex Nesting State

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, state, vuex

Assume we have the following App State in VueJS:

```
const state = {
  questions: [
    {
      text: 'Your prename?',
      answer: ''
    },
    {
      text: 'Hello {{ state.questions[0].answer }}, what\'s your surname?',
      answer: ''
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I render this nested state?

Comment: https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html

Comment: What do you mean by render nested state? Like what is the outcome do you want to achieve?